# Optimizing np.einsum calls in Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, linear-algebra, numpy-einsum

I have two numpy arrays: `X` of dimension `(N,N,N,N)` and `Y` of dimension `(N,N)`. My goal is to evaluate the following `einsum` call as fast as possible:

```
Z = np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y)
```

To do this, I benchmarked three implementations of the above, which yield identical answers but are optimized differently:

```
def einsum_one(X, Y):
    return np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y)

def einsum_two(X, Y):
    return np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y, optimize='optimal')

def fast_einsum(X, Y):
    Z = np.einsum('ij,iiii->ij', Y, X)
    W = np.einsum('il,ik->ikl', Y, Y)
    Z = np.einsum('ij,im->ijm', Z, Y)
    Z = np.einsum('ijm,ikl->jklm', Z, W)
    return Z
```

The way I got `fast_einsum` was by seeing the output of `np.einsum_path('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y, optimize='optimal')[1]`, which was:

```
  Complete contraction:  iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm
         Naive scaling:  5
     Optimized scaling:  5
      Naive FLOP count:  1.638e+05
  Optimized FLOP count:  6.662e+04
   Theoretical speedup:  2.459
  Largest intermediate:  4.096e+03 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2                 ij,iiii->ij                        ik,il,im,ij->jklm
   3                  il,ik->ikl                          im,ij,ikl->jklm
   3                  ij,im->ijm                            ikl,ijm->jklm
   5               ijm,ikl->jklm                               jklm->jklm
```

So, my expectation is as follows: for large `N`, `fast_einsum` should be the fastest, and `einsum_one` should be the slowest. For `einsum_two` there should be some overhead which is noticeable for small `N` but is negligible for large `N`. However, when I benchmarked the above, I obtained the following times (numerical values are in microseconds):

```
N | einsum_one | einsum_two | fast_einsum
4    15.1         949          13.8
8    256          966          87.9
12   1920         1100         683
16   7460         1180         2490
20   21800        1390         7080
```

So my implementation of `fast_einsum` is not optimal. So my question is: how do I interpret the output of `np.einsum_path` so that I can implement `np.einsum` as fast as possible without having to include the overhead of the `optimize='optimal'` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small `N=10` (my machine isn't large enough to use 100 (8Mb arrays)

But here some quick timings:

Precompute the path:

```
In [183]: path=np.einsum_path('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y,optimize=True)[0]
```

default:

```
In [184]: timeit M=np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y,optimize=False)
2.12 ms ± 4.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`True`:

```
In [185]: timeit M=np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y,optimize=True)
509 µs ± 687 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)


In [186]: timeit M=np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y,optimize='optimal')
3.31 ms ± 25.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`path` appears to be same for `True` and 'optimal', but the times are quite different.  I don't know why.

Using the precomputed path:

```
In [187]: timeit M=np.einsum('iiii,ij,ik,il,im->jklm', X, Y, Y, Y, Y,optimize=path)
291 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [188]: path
Out[188]: ['einsum_path', (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
```

Since all dimensions are the same, I'm not sure that path makes a big difference.  That is all `Y` are the same, so can be ordered in any way.  Anyways, the `path` calculation is, to some degree or other, hueristic, and not guaranteed to be optimal for all sizes.  As you found there's an important scaling factor, partly due to the cost of calculating the path, partly (I suspect) due to the size of the intermediate arrays, and the resulting memory management issues.

---

`einsum_path` explains the alternatives:

```
* if a list is given that starts with ``einsum_path``, uses this as the
  contraction path
* if False no optimization is taken
* if True defaults to the 'greedy' algorithm
* 'optimal' An algorithm that combinatorially explores all possible
  ways of contracting the listed tensors and choosest the least costly
  path. Scales exponentially with the number of terms in the
  contraction.
* 'greedy' An algorithm that chooses the best pair contraction
  at each step. Effectively, this algorithm searches the largest inner,
  Hadamard, and then outer products at each step. Scales cubically with
  the number of terms in the contraction. Equivalent to the 'optimal'
  path for most contractions.
```

Ok, this explains why 'optimal' is slower - it's looking for more alternatives.  Given these dimensions `True`, 'greedy' and 'optimal' end up with the same path.

Comment: It seems optimize=path is the way to get the speed up in einsum, compared with implementing the optimized path manually like I tried.